# Farm usage....present and present progressive

Tags: word-choice, usage, possessives

I have a question about present possessive for the word farm. Can you say, "Do you farm chickens?" Is that present possessive usage for farm?

I have heard, do you raise chickens?

I was told you could use farm as long as you have an object. However, I was told it is not common to say, do you farm chickens

Answer (score 2):

It isn't common, and 'raise' is the correct term. The verb 'farm' is used mostly for plants, not animals. However, chickens are raised on 'chicken farms'.